# Matlab plotting multiple functions

Tags: matlab, function, plot

If I have a function `myFunction(x,y,z)` like

```
function myFunction = (x,y)

for n=1:3
    f = x+y^n+1;
    plot(x,f)
end
```

how can I call this function in a separate script file to plot everything in one graph? This doesn't work:

```
hold on

myFunction(3,2)
myFunction(1,2)
```

Comment: Your `myFunction(x,y,z)` does not match your example. Maybe this is the reason? is a typo?

Comment: You need to open a figure window before you can do `hold on`. Either put the `hold on` between the 2 `myFunction` calls, or do `figure()` before the `hold on`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible answers,

```
function f = myfunction(x,y,fig)
if nargin<3;
    fig = gcf;
end

isHold = ishold(gca(fig));
hold on
n = 1:3;
f = x+y^.n+1;
plot(x,f,'o') % Or whatever marker you select
if ~isHold
    hold off;
end
```

If you only meant that you wanted to plot the points in the `for` loop everything of course become simpler.

```
function f = myfunction(x,y)
figure;
n = 1:3;
f = x+y^.n+1;
plot(x,f,'o'); % Or whatever marker you select.
% plot(x,f); % line plot
```

The simplest solution is however another. Replace the function with an anonymous function.

```
f = @(x,y,n) x+y^.n+1;
figure;
plot(x,f(x,y,1:3)); % Plot as a line plot
% plot(x,f(x,y,1:3),'o'); % plot as markers
```